# Inserting multiple formulas into columns sql

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a question about inserting multiple formulas into a data table, using sql.

I have a large data table, table g. Some columns of g are

```
    id1       id2      xyz
******************************
    123       456       4
    123       123       1
    789       456       5
    456       123       2
    123       789       4
```

I have created another table, placeholder, using these commands

```
CREATE TABLE placeholder(id, count, sum_1, sum_2)
```

Next, I am trying to insert data into placeholder and am running into an issue.

The variable 'id' in 'placeholder' can match one can match neither, one, or two of `id1 id2`. I have the `count` variable coded correctly, but I am struggling with a formula to insert data into sum_1 and sum_2.

`sum_1` needs to be a sum of `xyz`, grouped by id1

`sum_2` needs to be a sum of `xyz`, grouped by id2

I am trying to insert the data into placeholder using this code

```
INSERT INTO placeholder 
SELECT 
id1, 
COUNT(*) AS 'num' FROM g GROUP BY id1, 
SUM(xyz) AS 'num' FROM g GROUP BY id1,
SUM(xyz) AS 'num' FROM g GROUP BY id2
```

The first two lines work but the last two lines (beginnign with SUM) are not working. I keep getting the error  `OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error` .

How do I calculate the conditional sums and insert them into my table?

EDIT:

---

Here is what I would like placeholder to look like after my statement.

```
    id         count        sum_1         sum_2
*******************************************************
    123          3            9             3
    456          1            2             9
    789          1            5             4
```

these values correspond to the summed values in table g

Comment: Could you provide expected results given above data? it will help clairify intent

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with aggregation and `union all`:

```
select id, max(cnt) as cnt, sum(sum_1) as sum_1, sum(sum_2) as sum_2
from (select id1 as id, count(*) as cnt, sum(xyz) as sum_1, null as sum_2
      from g
      group by id1
      union all
      select id2, NULL as cnt, NULL as sum_1, sum(xyz) as sum_2
      from g
      group by id1
     ) gg
group by id;
```

Comment: When I run this code it is giving me a syntax error near "union"

Comment: @JoelSinofsky . . . I do not see anything obviously wrong with the `union all` in the subquery.